# Why is this button_to rendering incorrectly in Rails 3.2.11?

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working in Rails 3.2.11 and I cannot figure out why this button will not render per the API documentation. Specifically, I cannot get the data-remote attribute to render correctly. Is there a bug in my code?

Right now this code:

```
<%= button_to "Test", :action => "test", :remote => true, :form_class => "test_button" %>
```

yields this HTML:

```
<form action="/cloud_status/test?form_class=test_button&remote=true" class="button_to" method="post">
```

Per [the API specs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) it should render this:

```
<form action="/cloud_status/test" class="test_button" remote="true" method="post">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the documentation is actually incorrect here in some of the examples. The way to get the output you are looking for is:

```
<%= button_to "Test", { :action => "test" }, { :remote => true, :form_class => "test_button" } %>
```

The `:remote` and `:form_class` should be part of the `html_options` hash, which is the third parameter of the `button_to` method.

The second parameter can either be a `String` or `Hash`. When it's a `String` it's treated as a URL and when it's `Hash` it is passed to `url_for` to build the appropriate URL.

Comment: +1, it's not always clear which hash options belong in (or that there is even the possibility of there being two hashes because of Ruby's implicit hash sugar).

Comment: FYI: I've delivered a change to docrails to hopefully resolve this confusion: https://github.com/lifo/docrails/commit/741b291d660b298c0e39ce15e266f7d2cdfa8e2d